# Find arguments of a function in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

Please suggest me method to find declaration of an Argument passed to a Function in llvm IR.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `Function::getArgumentList()` method to get a list of function's arguments. Then, you traverse it with iterators - `ArgumentListType::begin()` and `ArgumentListType::end()`.

See `class Function` documentation - http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html

**UPD:**

The current way of iterating over arguments is `arg_begin()`/`arg_end()`/`args()` methods.

Comment: And with C++11's for-each structure, this is even easier. Let F be the function you are observing, and A be one argument of F's ArgumentListType: `for (auto& A : F.getArgumentList()) { A.dump(); }`

Comment: @arrowd the getArgumentList() is not mentionned in the documenation. Do you know why ?

Comment: I guess, my answer became outdated. I'll update it now.

Comment: Please note that this answer has become outdated in recent LLVM versions, as the `.getArgumentList()` function has been removed in favor of `.args()` iterator (see [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D31052) for more info).